# nginx : stop error log from search engine bots

Tags: nginx, logging

I have a centos 7 server with nginx 1.6.2 and I would like to stop error log when a bot from a search engine make a 404 error in my website.
This, in order to have a clean error log, with only "true errors".

How is it possible ?

I've tried this in my vhosts but it doesn't work

```
    server {
       ...
       error_log /var/log/nginx/errors.log;


       if ($http_user_agent ~* (googlebot|yahoo|bingbot)) {
          error_log /dev/null crit;
       }

       ...    
  }
```

In return, nginx service restart fail :

> nginx: [emerg] "error_log" directive is not allowed here in
>   /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.conf:18

An idea ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Any message in nginx `error.log` when restart fail?

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I've updated my post with nginx return

Comment: `with only "true errors".` - those are "true errors". There are requests (which if they come from a bot, mean there are or were links pointing at those urls) which you're not handling.

Comment: Yes AD7 but old external links that have not been updated

Comment: @Tof you should be returning e.g. a 410, or redirecting to somewhere relevant - i.e. tell the bots where to go or to stop checking for updates on things that aren't there. This kind of thing affects your search rankings, since you're just wasting the search-bot's resources.

Comment: AD7six : you're right, it seems the best solution ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found an intermediate solution :

```
server {
  ...
  error_log /var/log/nginx/errors.log;

  location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
    try_files $uri =410;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found  off;
   }
}
```

This code avoid error logging for no critical files.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log), direction `error_log` can't be used inside `if` context.

> **Syntax**:   error_log file | stderr | syslog:server=address[,parameter=value] [debug | info | notice | warn | error | crit | alert | emerg];
>
> **Default**:  error_log logs/error.log error;
>
> **Context**:  main, http, server, location

---

For  filtering `error_log` entry, you can't just rely on nginx. Some idea is using syslog to filter the log lines. [Nginx version 1.7.1 and above](http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html) support logging to syslog (of course you must update nginx version).

Every syslog software has different syntax for filtering. For example:

- rsyslog filter in [this page](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html)
- syslog-ng filter in [this wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/syslog-ng#Creating_Filters_for_Messages)

Of course you can just use `grep -v` for manually filtering bots from your log :).

Comment: Ok, but any idea to avoid error logs for bots ? ;-)

Comment: @Tof See updated answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but your solution looks like complicated. I hope a better one just with nginx ;-)